# "Column names in each table must be unique." during database update

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am quite new to ASP.NET at all, however this is my first app with ASP.NET Core. I have problem with updating database after creating the migration. While I type command: `dotnet ef database update`, I get error:

> Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'PortalUserId'
>   in table 'Adverts' is specified more than once.

I think the problem is with my model structure, but I do not know what I am doing wrong. When I was developing with ASP.NET MVC 5 everything was Ok.

Here is my Model (without unnecessary for the case entities):

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<PortalUser> PortalUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Advert> Adverts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}

public class Advert
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public int PortalUserID { get; set; }
    public PortalUser PortalUser { get; set; }
}

public class PortalUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Advert> Adverts { get; set; }

}
```

What I am doing here is normal virtual mapping for lazy loading purposes.  I am storing FK to PortalUser in Advert field.

I will appreciate every helpful answer!

I already figure out, that lazy loading is not supported so now my model looks like in the official tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db

```
    public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public BloggingContext(DbContextOptions<BloggingContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please avoid forcing tags into the title in future, unless it's natural part of the question / sentence, see HelpCenter: http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: You seem to have inconsistent capitalization. Did you try naming the property `PortalUserId` rather than `PortalUserID` (notice the lower-case D on the end? EF Core will by default trying to add `Id` to a foreign key if its not defined, and db columns aren't case sensitive. Your error message says `PortalUserId`, but your model has `PortalUserID`

Comment: I changed it to PortalUserId - update to database is done, however in the database structure I have now PortalUserId and PortalUserId1. So it seems to duplicate it. I have no idea why it is happening. In MVC such a thing does not happen.

Comment: Do you have anything else in your `OnModelCreating`? Also take a look in your migration files, to see what happened before. If you are still in early development phase, you can also drop the database + migration files and create a new initial migration or if you want more work, roll back until the point before `PortalUserId` was created for the first time

Comment: I have nothing more in `OnModelCreating`. I am creating the new database all the time. I figure out solution, however, which is strange for me. I just deleted FK: PortaluserID and left only PortalUser PortalUser property - then it is mapped to PortalUserId field in the database. Then only I dont understand why the example I mentioned above with Blogs and Posts, has doubled it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, guys, I found the solution! All what is needed, it is change type of property PortalUserId from int to string. Than everythings compiles and no doubled field appears!

Thanks for at least trying to help me!