# EF Core Identity Foreign Key throws Column names in each table must be unique

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I've created a model class that is intended to have a foreign key relationship with the Id field in the ASPNetUsers Identity table.  I read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40702704/column-names-in-each-table-must-be-unique-during-database-update) which is similar to mine but I'm unable to resolve based on the suggested answer.

My model class is defined as:

```
public class Execution
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Key]
    public int ExecutionId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TierForeignKey")]
    public int TierID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserForeignKey")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public Tier Tier { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

My user class extends IdentityUser as follows:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [PersonalData]
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    [PersonalData]
    public Boolean AcceptedEula { get; set; }
    [PersonalData]
    public string TemplateSelected { get; set; }
    [PersonalData]
    public DateTime DateTimeCreated { get; set; }
    [PersonalData]
    public DateTime DateTimeLastUpdated { get; set; }
    [PersonalData]
    public string GuacamoleUrl { get; set; }
    [PersonalData]
    public string GuacamoleUserName { get; set; }
    [PersonalData]
    public string GuacamolePassword { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserClaim> Claims { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserLogin> Logins { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserToken> Tokens { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationRoleClaim> RoleClaims { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<string>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<string>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationRoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<string>
{
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUserToken : IdentityUserToken<string>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(b =>
        {
            b.HasMany(e => e.Claims)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UserId)
                .IsRequired();
            b.HasMany(e => e.Logins)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(ul => ul.UserId)
                .IsRequired();
            b.HasMany(e => e.Tokens)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(ut => ut.UserId)
                .IsRequired();
            b.HasMany(e => e.UserRoles)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                .IsRequired();
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>(b =>
        {
            b.HasMany(e => e.UserRoles)
                .WithOne(e => e.Role)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
                .IsRequired();
            b.HasMany(e => e.RoleClaims)
                .WithOne(e => e.Role)
                .HasForeignKey(rc => rc.RoleId)
                .IsRequired();
        });
    }
```

When I call `Script-Migration` from package manager console, the resulting table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [Executions] 
(
    [ExecutionID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [UserID] INT NOT NULL,
    [TierID] INT NOT NULL,
    [UserId] NVARCHAR(450) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Executions] PRIMARY KEY ([ExecutionID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Executions_Tiers_TierID] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([TierID]) REFERENCES [Tiers] ([TierID]) 
                ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Executions_AspNetUsers_UserId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [AspNetUsers] ([Id]) 
                ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

How do I properly omit the errant `UserID` field from the generated table schema?

Comment: Any fluent configuration not shown? I'm asking because for some fields the casing doesn't match the EF conventions - like `Id` -> `ID`

Comment: @IvanStoev I've added the fluent configurations as part of my edit above.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Still doesn't explain where Application**ID** and User**ID** columns come from. The `[ForeignKey("TierForeignKey")]` and `[ForeignKey("UserForeignKey")]` annotations are incorrect, but probably are ignored by EF Core.

Comment: Why would you like to have it ignored in the database but not in the class definition? What value would you want this attribute to have then when you return the Execution objects from the dB context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the above issue by removing the current migration using package manager console and creating a new one.  In doing so, the new migration script reflected my changes properly and all is working as it should.  I feel that there was at least one if not more migrations that were causing the issue above.  Managing EF migrations and taking care to update the database only after reviewing the migration script are my two takeaways from this issue.